# ag-grid date column inRange filter - how do I access the "to" date in the test function?

Tags: date, filter, ag-grid, date-range

My `columnDef` for my date column includes this `filterOption`:

```
{
    displayKey: 'inRange',
    displayName: 'In range',
    test: function(filterValue, cellValue) {
        ...
    }
},
```

When I run, `filterValue` is just the 'from' date of the filter.  How do I access the 'to' date of the filter in `test`?

I tried:

```
{
    displayKey: 'inRange',
    displayName: 'In range',
    test: function(filterValue1, filterValue2, cellValue) {
        ...
    }
},
```

But that just puts the cell value into `filterValue2`, and `cellValue` is undefined.

How do I get the 'to' date so I can write my custom logic for `inRange`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had similar problem and was thinking to override using prototype overriding but I found another way which is kinda workaround but it works for me. you can call below method inside test function.

```
    gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();
```

this will get you the filtermodel on current column. You can use below code

```
    //getFilterModel() will give you filter JSON object
    var customfilterModel = gridOptions.api.getFilterModel(); 
    var columnName = Object.keys(customfilterModel)[0];
    var customDateFilter = customfilterModel[columnName];
```

`customDateFilter` variable will be object containing following properties

```
    {
    dateFrom: "2020-06-30" //the date which you selected in AGGridDateFilter Popup
    dateTo: "2020-08-27" //the date which you selected in AGGridDateFilter Popup
    filterType: "date"
    type: "inRange"
    }
```

now since you have both `dateFrom` and `dateTo` properties so I guess you know what you want to do with them.

I think AG Grid folks should update the

```
    return customFilterOption.test(filterText, cellValueFormatted);
```

above statement to return both `dateFrom` and `dateTo` like I mentioned below so that developer can customize the behavior for custom/complex dates.

```
    return customFilterOption.test(filterText, cellValueFormatted ,filterValueTo);
```

Comment: Thanks much!  I ended up using `getFilterInstance` instead of `getFilterModel` but wouldn't have found it without your answer.  Really strange that ag-grid makes us jump through these hoops.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar kind of problem. but using 'predicate' instead of 'test' it resolved.
predicate function takes array of values, depending on the 'number Of Inputs' defined.
https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-provided-simple/#reference-IFilterOptionDef-predicate
The usage will be like this:

```
{
      displayKey: 'inRange', displayName: 'In Range', numberOfInputs: 2, predicate: ([fv1, fv2], cellValue) => {
        var cellDate = new Date(cellValue);
        return (fv1 < cellDate && fv2 > cellDate);
      }

    }
```